# Android - How to extend application class mid-project for LeakCanary

Tags: android

**TLDR:**
***I have to extend the application class but don't know where to start.***

Ok... I know this is a dumb one but I have to ask it.

I need to install **LeakCanary** and I see in their documentation that it requires me to put code in the Application Class.

I understand how to make a java class that extends the application class, but I have some questions before I do this.

**SITUATION:**

1. I have 9 classes in my app already.
2. The entry point to my app is MainActivity.class (figures, right?)
3. I have not had to extend the Application Class yet.
4. App name is "CST-ALERT"

**QUESTIONS:**

1. Do I just create a new Java class in my java source folder and name it the same as my overall
   package name? What do I name this new class?
2. Do I need to adjust the manifest now to have this as the entry point
   instead of MainActivity? Which I imagine will change things quite a
   bit for me.
3. Do I have to change anything else in the manifest? I assume I will
   at least have to declare it in there.

Hopefully my situation and questions will give you an idea of what I am asking.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Do I just create a new Java class in my java source folder

Yes.

> and name it the same as my overall package name?

If by "it", you mean the Java package, you already have a directory for your existing Java code. Put your subclass of `Application` in there, unless you have a clear reason not to.

In [this trivial sample app](https://github.com/commonsguy/cw-omnibus/tree/master/Leaks/StaticWidgetLC), I put my `Application` subclass in the same directory as my launcher `Activity`, which is the directory for my Java package (`com.commonsware.android.button`).

> What do I name this new class?

That is up to you. I called it `CanaryApplication`. If you think you leak a lot, call it `CoalMine`. So long as it is a legal Java class name, it doesn't matter.

> Do I need to adjust the manifest now to have this as the entry point instead of MainActivity?

Um, well, I wouldn't describe `MainActivity` as the entry point. Regardless, `MainActivity` is left alone. You need to add an `android:name` attribute to the `<application>` element, identifying your `Application` subclass.

> Do I have to change anything else in the manifest?

No, that should suffice.

Comment: Couldn't have answered better !

Comment: DONE! Thank you! I will accept the answer as soon as the minimum window passes. I seriously do not understand how some of you guys are so fast on here!!!